# Import/Export Salesforce Knowledge articles

Tags: knowledge, data-import-wizard

I am using the Salesforce's OOTB feature for import/export Knowledge articles that can be found under Data Management --> Import Articles.

I have prepared the Zip file as per the instructions given below:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_article_importer.htm&type=5

I am able to import the articles but all imported articles are converted into "Draft" status and I am not able to mass convert the "PublishStatus" to "Online" also CSV is not accepting the column "PublishStatus" during importing data.

Any thoughts, how can I import all articles with Status "Online".

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

As per the help article [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000312783&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1), it's not possible to mass update an article's PublishStatus

One workaround which might help you solve this without having to update it manually from UI, is by using this [PublishingService Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_knowledge_kbManagement.htm). You can retrive all `Article Ids` and execute the method `publishArticle(articleId, flagAsNew)` of the `PublishingService` class from Execute Anonymous window

The `PublishingService` class doesn't have a method to pass list of `Article Ids`, so you might have to create a list and execute it in a for loop multiple times

Comment: Question is about what am I missing during importing articles that not able to set the PublishStatus.
Not looking for apex solution.

Comment: That is what I replied. You cannot mass update publish status. So provided workaround.